# If i insert a table into wicked-pdf then extra empty page is added at last while pdf generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce-4, wicked-pdf

```
I am using Tinymce editor to insert the Body content into pdf report
```

if i add the table into editor and try to reflect same thing in pdf report then one extra empty page is added at last in pdf-report, this happens only when table is inserted no problem with text paragraphs,images etc

And my wicked-pdf gem versions are
wkhtmltopdf (0.1.2)
wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.9.9.1)

this is for Rails2 app

Comment: width of the table is 115%

Comment: if my 2nd tr is lengthier than the available space in current page. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

put a div at last of your html code. like

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <% if question.id == @questions.last.id %>
    <div></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

or you may put a div according to your code.

After adding a division in your html.put the following line in your css:

```
div.alwaysbreak { page-break-before: always; }
div.nobreak:before { clear:both; }
div.nobreak{ page-break-inside: avoid; }
```

It works for me